# Node.js Error : Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I have a simple Node.js application using sticky-session, express and socket.io.
I have checked the Sticky-session library files and it should spawn a new worker once one of the other one dies, and so I tested to exit a process on 1 of the workers. But now instead of creating just a new worker, my whole application crashes and gives me this error :

```
emitting message: adad . socket.id=YcaiZWUFKlF12lD9AAAB . pid = 11448
emitting message: adadadad . socket.id=YcaiZWUFKlF12lD9AAAB . pid = 11448

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: channel closed
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:590:16)
    at Worker.send (internal/cluster/worker.js:54:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\Desktop\socket.io + node cluster + redis WORKING\node_modules\sticky-session\lib\sticky-session.js:54:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1554:8)
```

Here my Server Code

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var sticky = require('sticky-session');

var expressHandler = require("./handlers/expressHandler")
var redisHandler = require("./handlers/redisHandler")
var ioSocketHandler = require("./handlers/socketHandler")

var config = require("./configuration/default")
var port = config.web.port;
var workers = config.system.cores

var app = express();


///////////////////////////////////
//      HTTP SERVER
///////////////////////////////////

sticky(workers, function() {

  var server = http.createServer(app);

  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  redisHandler(io)

  ioSocketHandler(io)

  return server;

}).listen(port, function() {

  console.log(`server started on port ${port}. process id = ${process.pid}`);

});


///////////////////////////////////
//      EXPRESS
///////////////////////////////////

expressHandler(app)
```

And here the express module which causes the error on purpose

```
var config = require("../configuration/default")
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require("express-session")({
    secret: config.cookie.secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})

function initialiseExpressHandlers(app) {

    app.use(cookieParser());

    session.Cookie

    app.use(session);

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session)
        res.sendfile('index.html');
    });

    app.get('/kill', function(req, res) {
        process.exit(1);
    });

}

module.exports = initialiseExpressHandlers
```

And finally the Redis Adaptar I use to handle socket.io in a cluster. The other code should be irrelevant.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');

function initialiseRedisHandler(io) {

    var redisUrl = process.env.REDISTOGO_URL || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
    var redisOptions = require('parse-redis-url')(redis).parse(redisUrl);
    var pub = redis.createClient(redisOptions.port, redisOptions.host, {
        detect_buffers: true,
        auth_pass: redisOptions.password
    });
    var sub = redis.createClient(redisOptions.port, redisOptions.host, {
        detect_buffers: true,
        auth_pass: redisOptions.password
    });

    io.adapter(redisAdapter({
        pubClient: pub,
        subClient: sub
    }));
    console.log('Redis adapter started with url: ' + redisUrl);

}

module.exports = initialiseRedisHandler
```

Comment: what Version of Node are you running?

Comment: I am using v8.7.0

Comment: looks like a lot of errors relating to this are recent (ie late 2017), you could try updating your Node to v9+?

Comment: I just updated to 9.9 and it still throws a error.